# Move block inside another block

Tags: magento2, php, theme, phtml

I want to put the header.links into another block.
this is the icon.phtml file:

```
<div data-block="dropdown" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <i class='fas fa-user-circle action' data-trigger='trigger'></i>
</div>
```

the menu.phtml file:

```
<div id="links-menu" class="block block-minicart"
     data-mage-init='{
        "dropdownDialog": {
            "appendTo": "[data-block=dropdown]",
            "triggerTarget":"[data-trigger=trigger]",
            "timeout": 2000,
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "autoOpen": false,
            "triggerClass": "active",
            "parentClass": "active",
            "dialogContentClass": "active", 
            "buttons": []
        }
     }'>
    content
</div>
```

This is the layout file:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="icon_account" as="icon_account" template="Magento_Customer::/icon/icon.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="links-menu" as="links-menu" template="Magento_Customer::/menu/menu.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>

<move element="header.links" destination="links-menu"/>
```

The problem is that the header.links are not into the desired destination.
How can I fix it?

Full xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>  <!-- this is the css to render the icon of the account link -->
        <css src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer" template="account/customer.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login" template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>

        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <move element="header" destination="header.links" before="-"/>
        <move element="register-link" destination="header.links"/>
        <move element="my-account-link" destination="header.links"/>        
        <move element="top.links" destination="customer"/>
        <move element="authorization-link" destination="top.links" after="-"/>
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>


        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="icon_account" as="icon_account" template="Magento_Customer::/icon/icon.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="links-menu" as="links-menu" template="Magento_Customer::/menu/menu.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="header.links" destination="links-menu"/> 

        <move element="icon_account" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart"/>
        <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: write full xml.

Comment: where is the closing tag for `<referenceBlock name="header.links">`

Comment: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the layout file:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="icon_account" as="icon_account" template="Magento_Customer::/icon/icon.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="links-menu" as="links-menu" template="Magento_Customer::/menu/menu.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="links-menu-content" as="links-menu-content" template="Magento_Customer::/menu/content.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="header.links" destination="links-menu-content" after="-"/>
```

I created a content.phtml file:

```
<div id="minicart-content-wrapper">
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('header.links'); ?>
</div>
```

The menu.phtml file:

```
<div id="links-menu" class="block block-minicart"
     data-mage-init='{
        "dropdownDialog": {
            "appendTo": "[data-block=dropdown]",
            "triggerTarget":"[data-trigger=trigger]",
            "timeout": 2000,
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "autoOpen": false,
            "triggerClass": "active",
            "parentClass": "active",
            "dialogContentClass": "active", 
            "buttons": []
        }
     }'>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('links-menu-content'); ?>
</div>
```

the icon.phtml file:

```
<div data-block="dropdown" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <i class='fas fa-user-circle action' data-trigger='trigger'></i>
</div>
```

So the problem was this piece of code was missing:

```
 <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('child block name'); ?>
```

It is not implicit in the layout that the parent block call its child block.